# Javascript how to convert argument to a key?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I was trying the following code :

```
function doSomething(field, value) { 
   var someObj = { field : value };
   console.log("The object looks like : %j, someObj);
}
```

I call it like  doSomething('emailid', 'a@b.com');

```
The output was {field : 'a@b.com'}.
```

How can i make field to take the value from the function call?

```
Would like to get these values :  {'emailid', 'a@b.com'}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an object with the object literal syntax you can either speciy the name of the key as you did, like `{field: value}` or you can use string literals to define the key such as `{"field": value}`. Unfortunately there is no way to substitute a variable for a key with object literal syntax, but there is a way to accomplish your outcome.

```
function doSomething(key, value) {
  var someObj = {};
  someObj[key.toString()] = value;
  return someObj;
}
```

That should perform your task.

Comment: @voicestreams Glad to hear it!